# Why physics body automatically moves upwards in andengine gles2 anchor center live wallpaper

Tags: android, andengine, game-physics, live-wallpaper

I am trying to develop a live wallpaper using andengine gles2 anchor center , with some physics.But when i add a physics object it was moving upwards.instead of moving downward due to gravity 
what are the mistakes i am making 
please help me to sort out the issue

Here is my code

```
FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f,
                0.5f);
mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0,
                        SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
final AnimatedSprite animatedSprite;
animatedSprite = new AnimatedSprite(500, 250,
                        this.mBoxFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, animatedSprite,
                        BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

scene.attachChild(animatedSprite);
animatedSprite.animate(200);
mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(
                        animatedSprite, body, true, true));
```

Comment: Multiply the gravity by -1?

Comment: No i dont do anything its the code above no multiplaction

Comment: Perhaps change mPhysicsWorld into (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH, 0).

Comment: tried its not helps its make the gravity to the right side

Comment: Not exactly too knowledgeable about AndEngine/GLES2, but what's the parameters for `PhysicsConnector()`?

Comment: org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsConnector.PhysicsConnector(IEntity pEntity, Body pBody, boolean pUdatePosition, boolean pUpdateRotation)

Comment: I can't seem to pinpoint the exact error. Hopefully this might bring some insight: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/PhysicsExample.java

Comment: Thank you , Thank you David for your nice help hopes this will help me.. Thanks again

Comment: Hello David , You are right just need to multiply by -1 solve the issue what we have to do is just add a minus sign to  SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH like this  mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0,
                        -SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false); Please post you comment as an answer i willl mark it as the correct one

Comment: Glad to see that it's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just multiply `SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH` by -1.

Answer (score 0):

Setting negative gravity did not respond properly to sensor data. By adding acceleration to the sensor data in the overridden method `**onAccelerationChanged()**`, could make the bject falling down with sensor flat.

`public void onAccelerationChanged(final AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        /* Add constant value for vertical gravity*/
        final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerationData.getX(), pAccelerationData.getY() + 4.0);
        this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
        Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);
    }`

This will make your phy world in real gravity experience and you will get objects influenced by sensor data properly